# Why my Tensorflow FCN failed

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation

I implemented "Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation" on tensorflow. However my implementation can't learn anything meaningful and always resulted all 0 prediction or Nan value crash.

I tried all trick I have learned, weed out all difference between Caffe and Tensorflow. I am pretty much out of idea where it could be wrong now.

[link to code](https://github.com/24hours/tf_fcn)

Answer (score 0):

@24hours

I find it hard to dive into your code.

One thing that might help you is the following:

I use this code snippet in many projects to monitor all my trainable parameters and their gradients. An example is [this](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/CNN_tsc/blob/master/pic/tensorboard_hist.png?raw=true)

The code extracts all trainable variables, loops over them and requests a histogram

```
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads = tf.gradients(cost, tvars)
gradients = zip(grads, tvars)
# The following block plots for every trainable variable
#  - Histogram of the entries of the Tensor
#  - Histogram of the gradient over the Tensor
#  - Histogram of the grradient-norm over the Tensor
for gradient, variable in gradients:
  if isinstance(gradient, ops.IndexedSlices):
    grad_values = gradient.values
  else:
    grad_values = gradient

  h1 = tf.histogram_summary(variable.name, variable)
  h2 = tf.histogram_summary(variable.name + "/gradients", grad_values)
  h3 = tf.histogram_summary(variable.name + "/gradient_norm",
```

Comment: Hi, my codes are indeed a mess. I refactored them abit and hope it help readability.

Answer (score -1):

One more thing :
In your transpose convolution function call you are missing the argument of padding. I wonder how it would work without padding.
In any case you will have to set `padding =VALID` or `padding = SAME` while calling `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the default value for `padding` in `conv2d_transpose` is `same`. Since Tensorflow do not have `CROP` layer as in Caffe, I opt for same to maintain dimension. At the end, fcn worked on Tensorflow with the contraint on fixed sized image.